# How to move image vertically in c# wfp

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to move a car first horizontally then after some time like after 100 sec that car should be hidden and from that point a new car display and move vertically from that point.

here I am done with horizontally moving of car.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Interval = 40;
    timer1.Start();
}

int i = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time_for_car1_to_B();   
}

public void time_for_car1_to_B()
{
    i++;
    pictureBox1.Left += 2;

    label1.Text = i + "sec";

    if (i == 100)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        pictureBox1.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so if `Left += 2` moves it towards right then how about `Top += 2` or whatever?

Comment: oh yess, it works!